# Select the second instance of a character with regex

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I want to select the second 'M' in the following string using regex.
So, the M after T.

```
P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S
```

Sometimes the string looks like one of these:

```
PT12H30M5S
PT12H30M5.234523S
```

I've tried multiple expressions and searched for a similar case but couldn't find anything.

Could someone help me build an expression to select the M after T so I can use it in my regex replace function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?!.+T.+)(M)
```

Selects everything until the first T and then selects everything until the first M and captures it.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/sPbQQj/2

Comment: This will also match `P12H30M5S` when there is no `T` before `M`